# Call WCF Web Service using ASIHttprequest XCode4.2

Tags: c#, wcf, ios5, xcode4, asihttprequest

Hi I write simple WCF Service and uploaded in my local IIS(v7) server.
so the url is like that `http://mylink/WCF_SAMPLE/Service1.svc`. my wcf web service is tested with svcutil.exe so wcf web service is correct.

I try to consume the WCF Web service from AsiHttprequest. but it is fail. i check the response that show `<object returned empty description>`. here is my coding for IOS application.

```
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mylink/WCF_SAMPLE/Service1.svc"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/xml"];
[request setPostValue:@"john" forKey:@"fname"];
[request setPostValue:@"Carter" forKey:@"sname"];
[request setDelegate:self]; 
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Here is my web service code in IService1.cs:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1{
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method="POST",UriTemplate="/showemployeename")]
   string showemployeename(string fname,string sname);
}
```

Inside Service1.svc.cs

```
public class Service1:IService1{
 public string showemployeename(string fname,string sname)
 {
    return fname+sname
 }
}
```

Here is my web.config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
   <service name="WCF_SAMPLE.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCF_SAMPLE.Service1Behavior">
       <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCF_SAMPLE.IService1">
       </endpoint>
       <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behavior name="WCF_SAMPLE.Service1Behavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
   </behavior></system.serviceModel>
```

how to connect to WCF web service and how to grab showemployeename function ?

appreciate for any help

Best Rgds,
df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're configuring your `WCF_SAMPLE.Service1` service to use the `wsHttpBinding` instead of the `webHttpBinding`. This [short blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bashmohandes/archive/2008/01/05/using-webhttpbinding-json-support-in-wcf.aspx) gives a simple example of using the `webHttpBinding`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your time. do you mean webHttpBinding instead of wsHttpBinding ?

Comment: Right, your config shows `binding="wsHttpBinding"` and your service contact is marked with `WebInvoke` which is specific to `WebHttpBinding`. If you reconfigure your config file as shown in the sample link, your iOS client should receive the returned string as standard XML instead of a soap formatted XML message.